# Can I allow my puppy near my breast?

Tags: dogs, behavior, safety

Recently, my husband and I brought home a small, 15 day old puppy from a local shelter. Its mom has passed away so I have adopted it. I feed it with a bottle filled with milk from my pet goat.

The puppy is too attached to me and my family. Since 2 days ago, he is trying to come and play around my breasts, so can I allow it to do so? If not, please let me know the solutions.

Comment: i know very little about dogs but two weeks old sounds way to early for a puppy to be taken from the mother,it should live on mothersmilk a lot longer than this i belive.

Comment: https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/guide/caring-newborn-puppy#1

Comment: @trondhansen this is my opinion too, but maybe there was a special case, because OP wrote it comes from a shelter?

Comment: It would probably help if you describe what you're worried about. Spontaneously it sounds like the ideal place for a puppy.

Comment: I am just worried it is normal for him to come and sleep near my breast yes I am ok if it comes as it is just my small baby and.I am his mum . But want to know if its safe for both us

Comment: @trondhansen Its mom has passed away

Comment: @Darshna sad to hear this,thank you for adding this information so we get a clearer picture of the situation it is helpful to know for the ones answering your question.wellcome to pets.

Comment: This is not an answer but I stumbled across the following statement on this [veterinary website](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/feeding-orphaned-puppies): *"Puppies cannot eliminate (urinate or defecate) on their own until about 3 weeks of age. They rely on their mother to stimulate their reflex to initiate elimination. Orphaned puppies, on the other hand, rely on their caretakers to stimulate them to eliminate."* Puppy being unable to defecate could be life-threatening - if you can see a veterinarian, do so as a matter of urgency. Link from @trondhansen says same.

Comment: This can be done by a caretaker, but you need to learn how to do it. I've seen panda caretakers help baby pandas to go pee and poo.

Comment: @TomW I asked a second question about the special care for an orphaned puppy. Please make your comment an answer there and get the deserved reputation for it! https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28057/how-to-care-for-an-orphaned-puppy

Comment: You will be fine the pup will think you are the mother and let him touch your breast. If you are pregnant you can give the pup your own milk.

Comment: From personal observation, babies can smell breasts even on women who are not lactating. Maybe pups can smell human breasts too?

Comment: I am neither lactating nor pregnant I have son of 23 years. But still my breasts are big so may be my puppy likes it. Its ok I allow him on my breasts. Also one of my friend is lactating mother so can I keep him with her for feeding she has extra milk and ready to serve the kid.

Answer (score 39):

15 days is way too young to separate a puppy from the mother. Like Trond Hansen wrote, the puppy has to eat mother's milk in this age to be healthy and it needs the body of the mum to stay warm and comfortable.

This could be the reason the puppy searches for the body contact with you. The near breast is not its aim I believe, because there is no smell of milk (I assume you have worries about this? Am I right?) in case you are no new mum now.

You write "the puppy is too much attached" but this I assume is normal in this age. Being 15 days old, a puppy has no (really NO) chance to live without the support of other (normally the mum) animals. It knows this and is active searching for protection. It wants to stay close and be sure it is protected by someone against enemies, cold and hunger. Its understanding does not reach through a door, over a "normal" distance or differ between nature and your home. Because of that, it needs short distance to its protectors (you and your family) to feel good and be the best puppy it could be.

Comment: Its mom has passed away so I have adopted it. I feed it with bottle milk of my pet goat. Also at time I keep him to got nd he suckles it also . Just to make sure is it safe if he stays near my breasts?

Comment: @Darshna Good to hear you've got the goat milk. Yes, your breasts are safe with your puppy.

Answer (score 21):

15 days is extremely young for a puppy to be away from its mother, that said it sounds like you ended up with the puppy from a local shelter, so the mother or a surrogate mother may not be available.

If that is a case I would recommend you go that shelter or a veterinarian to find out the best care regimen for the puppy in terms of diet and socialization. This is going to be a difficult time for both you and the puppy as they will require a lot of extra attention.

Related to your direct question, I doubt that the puppy is trying to suckle from you, and I suspect that it is really seeking warmth and comfort, and is just trying to stay as close to you as possible. Young puppies spend most of their time either in a pile with their litter-mates or right up against their mother, so it is just trying to replicate that with you. In order to keep the puppy comfortable and calm you may want to buy a number of warm and soft plush toys that they can snuggle up with to simulate their typical puppy behavior.

Disclaimer: I am not a vet or an expert on puppy well-being, and you should follow any expert advice you can get on the matter

Comment: OP has confirmed that the mother passed away.

Answer (score 6):

Keep up the feeds, give the puppy plenty of affection, cuddles and keep it warm.

There's no need for the puppy to play with your breasts per se. Unless you are lactating, in which case a very young animal may be drawn to human breasts, the puppy will not relate human breasts to being fed. The puppy will be looking for comfort and safety.

I'd recommend getting the puppy vet checked and ensure that all its nutritional needs are being met. At some point you will need to address this, as puppies start weaning at around 6 weeks and there is a progression onto solids.